# Passing a multiline string as parameter to js function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, frontend, nopcommerce

When calling `displayBarNotification(stringIPass, 'success', 3500)` of `nopcommerce` originally defined in `public.common.js` seems the call fails when *`stringIPass`* contains `newlines`.
The error on the client-side was something like

> Unexpected line break in a string literal

I tried replacing the `C#` newline character in the ajax function to the js equivalent and it worked. However, I intend to keep the "newlines" for readability reasons. What approach would you suggest?

Pardon me for the lack of the exact error expr. but it's because I'm currently not at work. I will update tomorrow if necessary.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: You can use the javascript scape function first

Answer (score 6):

Official documentation:

> **Template literals** are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.

Use back-ticks ( ` ) to introduce a template literal:

```js
var example = `
  this
  is
  a
  test
`;

console.log(example);
```